# Not all topics publishing data

Tags: mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

A few topics macros topics won't publish. But most do. I am interested in getting the topic /mavros/rc/out. However, whenever I

`$rostopic echo /mavros/rc/out'

There is no data.

I have a Pixhawk with the px4 flight stack and I am connecting it to a raspberry pi 2 running ubuntu with ROS indigo. Does anyone know of a solution to this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218252/not-all-topics-publishing-data/) by [KBrown](https://answers.ros.org/users/23689/kbrown/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That depends on how you setup connection. If using `SYS_COMPANION` parameter then you should request servo topics.

Place extras.txt on your SD card to `etc` folder (full path: `/fs/microsd/etc/extras.txt`):

```
#!nsh
# additional streams for SYS_COMPANION
mavlink stream -d /dev/ttyS2 -s SERVO_OUTPUT_RAW_0 -r 20
```

Also here example how to autostart ros on rpi2: https://github.com/vooon/rarog/tree/master/rarog_configs/rpi2

---

Originally posted by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) with karma: 404 on 2015-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KBrown](https://answers.ros.org/users/23689/kbrown/) on 2015-09-25**:
Excellent, it worked. Thank you very much.